# Why is simulating select option with javascript not making API calls?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the site I'm working on.

https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/doomben_181834/tab-long-may-we-play-class-3-handicap_1047245/#SectionalTimes

I want to select **Last 5 runs** option instead of **Last 10 runs** with javascript.

Here's what I did.

```
document.getElementById("sectionalSpeedRunsFilter").selectedIndex = "1";
```

Doing this worked in a way because it selected the **Last 5 runs** option.

But my problem is, on selecting **Last 5** with `javascript`, it doesn't make the **API call** as it does on selecting with mouse manually. So data, doesn't get updated.

How do I fix this ? Any help is appreciated. Fellow developers, please go easy on me, I'm just trying to solve a problem I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to trigger change event manually with [javascript](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually-in-javascript) after updating the value. Instead of `selectedIndex` use `value`

```
document.getElementById("sectionalSpeedRunsFilter").value = "1";
const e = new Event("change");
const element = document.querySelector('#sectionalSpeedRunsFilter')
element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Working sample.

```js
function onCarSelect() {
    const selectedCar = document.getElementById('sectionalSpeedRunsFilter').value;
    console.log(`You have selected ${selectedCar}`);
  }

  function setManually() {
    document.getElementById("sectionalSpeedRunsFilter").value = "opel";
    const e = new Event("change");
    const element = document.querySelector('#sectionalSpeedRunsFilter')
    element.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="sectionalSpeedRunsFilter" onchange="onCarSelect()">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="setManually()">Select Opel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: still not making API call. Did you try this on your browser ? Is it working? It is only selecting the option !

Comment: Very descriptive answer, thank you !  still it is not making API call for this site. :(

Comment: @Is the change event getting triggered?

Comment: If it was triggered, I think data should have loaded like it normally does when clicking with mouse, right ? So no. Maybe event is not triggered. P.S. 
```
$(document).on("change", ".sectional-filters__select", function() {
    var e, t, n, i, s;
    e = $("#sectionalSpeedRunsFilter").val(),
```
I found this jquery in the site.

Comment: So, it must be a change event. Maybe event is not being triggered.

Comment: @SauravPathak tru to debug the code. See whether the control goes into the change function.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed change event is firing too. I used onchange on <select> element and it logs the right value. I don't know what it is now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220478/discussion-between-saurav-pathak-and-nitheesh).

Comment: You were right about dispatching event manually. However, I had to set bubbles to true in event to make it work.